# How do I set different styles for different kinds of files in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, fonts

I want to use different styles for different kinds of files in Notepad++. For example, while editing a `.py` file, I want **Consolas** font and **10** font size and when editing a `.txt` file, I want **Arial** font and **12** font size.

Can I do this? I have tried to config the font and font size in Style Configurator seperately. Both in Global Styles(for `.txt` file, since I haven't found "Normal text" or "text" in the Language menu) and Python Default Styles, I've chosen different fonts, but when I open `.txt` file and `.py` file, there are both style in Global Styles being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, though maybe not as convenient as you'd want.

As you deduced, to set the Normal Text (`.txt`) format, you use **Global Styles > Default Style**.  Also, go into **Global Styles > Global Override**, and make sure you *don't* have `Enable Global xxxx` set -- unless you want every language to use that same `xxxx` that you have defined in the **Global Override** page.

Then, go to **Python**, and for *every one* of the styles, you need to set the font to your Python font (**Consolas**/**10**).  One might think that the **DEFAULT** settings for a given language would apply to any other style in the same language that doesn't set the font, but that doesn't work in this case; instead, the **DEFAULT** in a language is just used for any text that isn't otherwise styled in that language, and each style in the language inherits from the **Global Styles > Default Style** if it doesn't set its own font.

For my screenshot, the **Global Styles > Default Style** was set to `DejaVu Sans Mono`, and all the **Python** fonts were set to `Comic Sans MS` (to be easily seen; I don't normally code Python in Comic Sans :-) )

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thank you! It works well, and you also explain why only those white spaces changed when I changed the font size of Python. Very much thanks!